# Key Value Coding keyPath @sum of product of values?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data, key-value-coding

I have `NSManagedObject` with a 'one-to-many' relationship to a set of items. I love how I can use KVC keyPaths to easily get `quantity` below as a sum across all my items.

```
- (NSNumber *)quantity
{
    return [self valueForKeyPath:@"items.@sum.quantity"];
}
```

Now I want to know if it's possible to do the something similar here for `value`. Something like `@"items.@sum.(quantity * value)"` ?

```
- (NSNumber *)value
{
    double value = 0;
    for (Item *item in self.items)
    {
        value += [[item quantity] doubleValue] * [[item value] doubleValue];
    }
    return [NSNumber numberWithDouble:value];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do this.

Just add a new property to the `Item` class and override the getter

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSNumber *totalValue;

...

- (NSNumber *)totalValue
{
    return [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[self.value doubleValue] * [self.quantity doubleValue]];
}
```

Now you can use `@"items.@sum.totalValue` as a keyPath

Answer (score -2):

No. Sometimes you just gotta write code.